# Может ли сайт украсть пароль из браузера, если я его не вводил на сайте?

Tags: безопасность

Суть вопроса: Может ли сайт украсть пароли, сохранённые в браузере, без программ-стиллеров на моём пк или фишинга?
Объясните, а то доказываю уже пол часа другу, что нет, а он не верит)

Comment: Не может, если что-то не введёт его на странице автоматически (например автозаполнение менеджером паролей)

Comment: @andreymal и вправду через js изи отследить, даже без нажатия каких-либо кнопок, надо будет задуматься в следующий раз

Answer (score 1):

**Варианты всегда есть!** Через инструмент **beef-xss**, если пользователь перейдёт по определённой ссылке(Не углубляюсь в подробности для предотвращения блокировки, тот кто хочет найти информацию, может поискать в [интернете](https://searx.be)) которая используется злоумышленником с установленным **beef-xss** и злоумышленник получает возможность получить не только ваши cookies, но и следить за вашим трафиком и получать информацию о ваших посещениях и ещё множество других функций о которых говорить нельзя :), но, впрочем, это уже совсем другая история...